# Can spinnaker prevent out-of-order deployments?

Tags: spinnaker

### Currently

We use a CI platform to build, test, and release new code when a new PR is merged into master. The "release" step is quite simple/stupid, and essentially runs `kubectl patch` with the tag of the newly-pushed docker image.

### The Problem

When two PRs merge at about the same time (ex: `A`, then `B` -- `B` includes `A`'s commits, but not vice-versa), it may happen that `B` finishes its build/test first, and begins its release step first. When this happens, `A` releases second, even though it has older code. The result is a steady-state in which `B`'s code has been effectively rolled-back by `A`s deployment.

We want to keep our CI/CD as continuous as possible, ideally **without**:

- serializing our CI pipeline (so that only one workflow runs at a time)
- delaying/batching our deployments

Does Spinnaker have functionality or best-practice that solves for this?

Answer (score 0):

Best practises for your issue are widely described in Message Ordering for Asynchronous systems. The simpliest solution would be to implement FIFO priciple for your CI/CD pipeline. 
It will save you from implementing checks between CI and CD parts.